# best prediction technique for small dataset

Tags: time-series, prediction

What's the best way to predict till the time value is 40.

```
time value   bandwidth usage  sent packets 
0                 2666            139
1                 2217            118
2                 1997            124
3                 1998            110
4                 1928            103
5                 2142             87
6                 2054             95
```

Comment: Try moving average

Comment: the problem is with such limited data, how can one predict 40 data points moving forward

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to predict what the numbers would look like till time stamp 40.

Comment: unfortunately I just have these data points available